# Select network nodes with a given attribute value

Tags: python, networkx

I'd like to select and perform operations on nodes within a graph with particular attributes. **How would you select nodes with a given attribute value?** For example:

```
P=nx.Graph()
P.add_node('node1',at=5)
P.add_node('node2',at=5)
P.add_node('node3',at=6)
```

Is there a way to select only the nodes with  at == 5?.

I'm imagining something like (this doesn't work):

```
for p in P.nodes():
    P.node[p]['at'==5]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Python <= 2.7:**

According to the [documentation](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph.add_node) try:

```
nodesAt5 = filter(lambda (n, d): d['at'] == 5, P.nodes(data=True))
```

or like your approach

```
nodesAt5 = []
for (p, d) in P.nodes(data=True):
    if d['at'] == 5:
        nodesAt5.append(p)
```

**Python 2.7 and 3:**

```
nodesAt5 = [x for x,y in P.nodes(data=True) if y['at']==5]
```

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer, I used this: `[x for x,y in P.nodes(data=True) if y['at']==5]`

Comment: @atomh33ls Great. Yes, with list comprehension it is also possible. If you will use lot's of nodes may prefer `filter`. It should be "a little" faster.

Comment: Beware that the `lambda (n, d)` tuple unpacking syntax no longer works in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample code if someone is stuck**

```
import networkx as nx

P=nx.Graph()
P.add_node('node1',at=5)
P.add_node('node2',at=5)
P.add_node('node3',at=6)

# You can select like this
selected_data = dict( (n,d['at']) for n,d in P.nodes().items() if d['at'] == 5)
# Then do what you want to do with selected_data
print(f'Node found : {len (selected_data)} : {selected_data}')
```