# is it possible to get networkx dijkstra to avoid certain edges?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dijkstra

I have a problem where I have a directed (or non-directed) non-weighted graph, and I need to find the simple path from s-t. The only complication is that I need to avoid certain nodes that are marked red.

I found the python NetworkX graph library, and found it very fitting. I would like to use either the networkx.dijkstra_path() (or maybe the bfs function which could work as well) to find a shortest path.

In this code, I build a very simple graph, and find a path from s = 0 to t = 4:

```
import networkx


G = networkx.Graph()

for i in range(5):
    G.add_node(i)

# from zero
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(0,3)

# from 1
G.add_edge(1,2)

# from 2
G.add_edge(2,4)

# from 3
G.add_edge(3,4)

path = networkx.dijkstra_path(G, 0, 4)
```

This network has these nodes:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
These Edges:
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
And the dijkstra gives us this path from 0-4:
[0, 3, 4]
The graph looks like this visually (made with matplotlib):

[image]

But now I would like to be able to say that node 3 was red. So that we would need to avoid it. This would make the shortest path [0,1,2,4]. Is there any way to obstruct node 3 so that dijkstra could avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any inbuilt function that can do this. However, you can try the following steps to get the desired result:

- Add a node attribute based on which you will filter the nodes while creating the Graph.
- Filter the nodes and create a subgraph.
- Call the Dijkstra function on the new subgraph

  ```
  import networkx 

  G = networkx.Graph()

  #Add an attribute color
  for i in range(5):

      if i==3:
          G.add_node(i, color='red')
      else:
          G.add_node(i, color='blue')

  # Add edges
  G.add_edge(0,1)
  G.add_edge(0,3)
  G.add_edge(1,2)
  G.add_edge(2,4)
  G.add_edge(3,4)

  # Functin to get filtered subgraph
  def get_filtered_graph(G, ignore_attribute, ignore_val):
      # Filter the nodes based on the node attribute and value
      # In this case it is red color
      filtered_nodes = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True)
                     if y[ignore_attribute]!=ignore_val]

      # Create the subgraph
      H = G.subgraph(filtered_nodes)
      return H

  ignore_attribute ='color'
  ignore_val = 'red'
  path = networkx.dijkstra_path(get_filtered_graph(G, filter_attribute, filter_val), 0, 4)

  print(path)
  # [0, 1, 2, 4]
  ```

**References:**

- [Select Nodes and edges with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350222/select-nodes-and-edges-form-networkx-graph-with-attributes)
- [Select nodes with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922917/select-network-nodes-with-a-given-attribute-value)
- [NetworkX - Add Node](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [single_source_dijkstra](https://testfixsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra.html) function, with a filter function for the weight:

- Set a 'red' attribute to edges linked to node 3
- Use the code:

```
length, path = networkx.single_source_dijkstra(G, 0, 4, weight=lambda u, v, d: 1 if d['color']!="red" else None)
```