# Trouble retrieving nodes by attributes in NetworkX

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, graph-theory, dictionary-comprehension

I am developing a code using NetworkX in which I have a Multipartite graph similar to the following:

[image]

Each node has the following attributes:

- Layer: it refers to the column of the graph a node can be found
- Label: for each column I assign a label to each node
- Trajectory: it is a relation between nodes. If a node is related to another, the these to node may be labelled differently but will share a same trajectory.

In the photo above, each node label is depicted as 'label.layer' (in this case we can see a subset of a bigger graph, hence the layer number starts at 451 and not at 0).

What I would like to get are separate dictionaries from this graph, and these dictionaries should only contain the nodes which belong to the same trajectory, that is, all the nodes which are neighbours between each other. So far I followed these posts and my solution is:

[Select network nodes with a given attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922917/select-network-nodes-with-a-given-attribute-value)

[Select nodes and edges form networkx graph with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350222/select-nodes-and-edges-form-networkx-graph-with-attributes)

```py
for i in range(trajectory):
        sel_nodes = dict((node, attribute['trajectory']) for node, attribute in G.nodes().items() if attribute['trajectory'] == i)
        print(sel_nodes)
```

This should return a dictionary for each 'row' of nodes, however the output are the following dicts:

```
{'0.451': 0, '0.452': 0, '0.453': 0, '0.454': 0, '0.455': 0, '0.456': 0, '0.457': 0, '0.458': 0, '0.459': 0, '0.460': 0}
{'1.451': 1, '1.452': 1, '1.453': 1, '1.454': 1, '1.455': 1, '1.456': 1, '1.457': 1, '1.458': 1, '1.459': 1, '1.460': 1}
{'2.451': 2, '3.452': 2, '3.453': 2, '3.454': 2, '3.455': 2, '3.456': 2, '3.457': 2, '3.458': 2, '3.459': 2, '4.460': 2}
{'3.451': 3, '2.452': 3, '2.453': 3, '2.454': 3, '2.455': 3, '2.456': 3, '2.457': 3, '2.458': 3, '2.459': 3, '3.460': 3}
{'4.451': 4, '4.452': 4, '4.453': 4, '4.454': 4, '4.455': 4, '4.456': 4, '4.457': 4, '4.458': 4, '4.459': 4, '5.460': 4}
{'5.451': 5, '5.452': 5, '5.453': 5, '5.454': 5, '5.455': 5, '5.456': 5, '5.457': 5, '5.458': 5, '5.459': 5, '6.460': 5}
{'6.451': 6, '6.452': 6, '6.453': 6, '6.454': 6, '6.455': 6, '6.456': 6, '6.457': 6, '6.458': 6, '6.459': 6, '7.460': 6}
{'7.451': 7, '7.452': 7, '7.453': 7, '7.454': 7, '7.455': 7, '7.456': 7, '7.457': 7, '7.458': 7, '7.459': 7, '8.460': 7}
{'8.451': 8, '8.452': 8, '8.453': 8, '8.454': 8, '8.455': 8, '8.456': 8, '8.457': 8, '8.458': 8, '8.459': 8, '9.460': 8}
{}
{}
```

The last two empty dicts should be containing the lower line of nodes, and the lonely node at the last column of the graph, respectively, however it is not the case and I am only able to retrieve the nodes which are somehow connected to the first column.

Is there some way to fix this behaviour?

EDIT: To narrow down the problem a little bit, I believe the problem lies in the dictionary comprehension I used, since I have checked if the attribute trajectory has a value assigned to it by doing:

```py
print(G.nodes['9.455']['trajectory'])
```

And the output gives me trajectory 9, which is coherent with which I expect the trajectory to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a list of dicts is the wrong data structure here. It seems like what you're really looking for a data structure that tells you, given a trajectory `i`, which nodes belong to this trajectory? A dict of sets or list of sets seems like a better fit.

Here is how you could construct such a list on a small example graph where the top trajectory is an isolated node and the bottom two cross over each other:

```py
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from([(0.3, {"trajectory": 0}), (1.1, {"trajectory": 1}), (2.2, {"trajectory": 1}), (2.3, {"trajectory": 1}), (2.1, {"trajectory": 2}), (1.2, {"trajectory": 2}), (1.3, {"trajectory": 2})])
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for node, attrs in G.nodes().items():
...     d[attrs["trajectory"]].add(node)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {0: {0.3}, 1: {1.1, 2.2, 2.3}, 2: {1.2, 2.1, 1.3}})
```

If you really want the list of dicts as described above, you can easily construct it from here:

```
>>> for trajectory, nodes in d.items():
...     print({node: trajectory for node in nodes})
... 
{0.3: 0}
{1.1: 1, 2.2: 1, 2.3: 1}
{1.2: 2, 2.1: 2, 1.3: 2}
```

If you want an ordered list for each trajectory instead of a set, you can sort on the part of the name which comes after the decimal point:

```py
>>> d = {k: sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: str(x)[2:]) for k, nodes in d.items()}
>>> d
{0: [0.3], 1: [1.1, 2.2, 2.3], 2: [2.1, 1.2, 1.3]}
```

Comment: Really thankful for that, it works perfectly. I am relatively new to Python and in all honesty I did not know what sets were, but they certainly seem like a much better solution to what I was planning.

Comment: The only drawback I can see it's that the set is unordered and since my graph shows somewhat of a time progression it would be nice to have it ordered for me to later analyse de subsets. But that I can surely find a solution for.

Comment: With your naming scheme, it's easy to convert the sets into lists which give you the ordered sequence of nodes for each trajectory. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: That's great! I guess comprehension in Python is key to achieve many things... I guess I should learn how it works because I had no idea how powerful it can be. Again, really thankful for your answers.